# Let gamma t be a curve in R3. Prove if each component is a quadratic, then the curve is planar

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have that all components are of the form ax^2+bx +c. I think I recognize I need to show the torsion is zero and then the curve never twists out of the plane. Is this correct? There are two parts to the question, if the curve is contained in a plane, then each component is quadratic. And the curve is contained in a plane only if each component is quadratic. I can’t get much further than the torsion idea. Someone mentioned looking at gamma when t=0 which would just be a constant function, but I’m not sure how that helps

Thx
Marco

Answer (score 4):

Supposing each component is quadratic: Choose $A,B,C\in\Bbb R^3$ so that $$\gamma(t)=t^2A+tB=C.$$Now $$\gamma'(t)=2tA+B.$$Since $A$ and $B$ cannot span $\Bbb R^3$ there exists a *nonzero* $N\in\Bbb R^3$ with $A\cdot N=B\cdot N=0$. So $$\gamma'(t)\cdot N=0$$for all $t$. Hence $\gamma(t)\cdot N$ is constant: $$\gamma(t)\cdot N=c.$$So $\gamma$ lies in the plane defined by $x\cdot N=c$.

Comment: That's true...but given the context, I might have chosen a different name for $N$; in curve theory, that's often the normal to the curve. (I know, normal to the plane, normal to the curve...things are overloaded...)

Answer (score 3):

The claim is false as stated. Let $\gamma(t) = (t, \sin t, 0)$; that's a planar curve (it lies in the plane $z = 0$) but the second entry is definitely not quadratic.

I suspect the thing you want to prove is that if each component is a quadratic, *then* the curve is planar (i.e., the converse of what the title states). That second statement is (fortunately) actually true.

To prove the second statement, you might want to look at the binormal vector. If the curve IS planar, what can you say about the binormal? What about the converse?

Alternatively, you could show that in the three-dimensional space of quadratic univariate polynomials, any three points lie in some affine plane, and then try to interpret that statement geometrically as a statement about $\gamma$.

Comment: Yeah prove or disprove. Ok so that answers half of the question. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a counter example of a planar curve that has a non zero entry for z?

Comment: The exact question states a) the curve is contained in a plane if each component is quadratic

Comment: And b) the curve is contained in a plane only if each component is quadratic